# Need help to UPDATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  
CASE WHEN region =  'LUZON'
THEN dem_rtdel
END ) AS luzon_demand, MA 
CASE WHEN region =  'VISAYAS'
THEN dem_rtdel
END ) AS visayas_demand, MA 
CASE WHEN region =  'SYSTEM'
THEN dem_rtdel
END ) AS system_demand
FROM pub_demand_lwap
WHERE DATE
BETWEEN  '2013-11-14'
AND  '2013-11-15'
GROUP BY DATE
```

I have actually 4 tables and i need to get the 
specific columns in each table and put into table E 
i use select case to separate value into one column into 3column 
now i need help  that once that four table had encounter changes table E will automatically update the date.

Comment: What do you mean by update?

Comment: improve the question quality

Comment: flagged as "low quality post".

Comment: Please change the title to describe the type of change needed. As is, it is not clear.

Comment: I have two table A and B they were connected once u change something in table a table b will automatically update the data

Comment: check below link it may help you::::
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39103/A-Simple-Use-of-SQL-CASE-Expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are saying that on change in four table you want to update the record in 5th table.

For this purpose you can write an update trigger which will trigger on change on any one of the four tables and check if the needed values in four tables are updated and it will change accordingly the required column.

Comment: do you have any sample for this Sir? i really need some help..

Comment: check below link for update trigger:::                http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/OPUH170312-After-Trigger,-Instead-of-Trigger-Example.html